# Why does epsilon caprolactone not have triplets on 1H NMR?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

Looking at the structure of epsilon caprolactone (CL), you'd assume that the methylene protons (CH2) on either side of the ester would give you triplets. However, experimentally those peaks actually look more like inverted triplets (happens in both 300 and 400 MHz NMR machines and in both CDCl3 and C6D6). Anyone know what causes this splitting pattern?

[image]

Comment: That seems to be the result of second-order effects due to small shift differences relative to the J-couplings.

Comment: It has to do something with the seven-membered ring because the linear polymer of caprolactone has the spectrum you would expect.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a simulated 1D $^1H$ NMR spectrum of gamma-caprolactone available from the [Human Metabolome Database (entry HMDB0060476)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgZnm.jpg) at 100 MHz in D2O.

[image]

The following is a blow-up of the downfield multiplet due to the epsilon proton (labelled "a" in the OP spectrum)

[image]

The splitting pattern might look elaborate but approximates a standard low-order ddd multiplet (not a triplet) as taught in introductory chemistry.

It might be unexpected however to see a ddd pattern. The origin is the nonequivalence of the geminal protons and of couplings to vicinal protons. The geminal epsilon protons have slightly different chemical shifts and are coupled through a relatively large (for a homonuclear coupling) ~10.6 Hz 2J coupling.
The vicinal delta protons resonate~2 ppm away (200 Hz in the simulated spectrum) and are coupled through 1.3 Hz and 5.4 Hz couplings (these differing between trans and cis protons).

Complex splitting patterns diverging from first-order are common in homonuclear NMR spectra with narrow spectral widths and close proximity of chemical shifts, particularly at low magnetic fields. This might also be the case here and might explain the unexpected multiplet peak intensities.
As explained in [this site](https://www.orgchemboulder.com/Spectroscopy/nmrtheory/splittingcomplex.shtml):

> Second order effects occur when the ratio of the chemical shift separation in Hz to the coupling constant is less than approximately 10.

Note that the field magnitude (in Hz) relative to the J-coupling is important. Simpler multiplet patterns are observed when shift differences are large relative to couplings, for instance when J-couplings are heteronuclear or when the applied magnetic field is incremented (also, as suggested in comments, when the symmetry of geminal protons is not broken by a ring structure). Such multiplets are often slanted in appearance (the "roof" effect). This is often seen in spectra otherwise lacking complex splitting patterns.